# Service not responding to ping command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, ping

My service (myservice.com) which is hosted in EC2 is up and running. I could see java process running within the machine but not able to reach the service from external machines. Tried the following option,

1. dns +short myservice.com
2. ping myservice.com

(1) is resolving and giving me ip address. `ping` is causing 100% packet loss. Not able to reach the service.

Not sure where to look at. Some help to debug would be helpful.

**EDIT**:

I had an issue with previous deployment due to which service was not starting - which I've fixed and tried to update - but the deployment was blocked due to ongoing deployment (which might take ~3hrs to stabilize). So I tried enabling `Force deployment` option from the console

[image]

Also tried minimising the "Number of Tasks" count to 0 and reverted it back to 1 (Reference: [How do I deploy updated Docker images to Amazon ECS tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34840137/how-do-i-deploy-updated-docker-images-to-amazon-ecs-tasks)) to stop the ongoing deployment.

Can that be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to allow ICMP protocol in the security group.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html#sg-rules-ping

Comment: Thank you for the link. My service was up and running sometime back so i think the security group rules must have been configured properly. But i did two things before hitting this problem 1) enabling `force deployment` from AWS console 2) Reducing the number of tasks to 0 and then made it back to 1. Can this cause some issue?