# How to update ECS container/TASK through Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ecs, continuous-deployment, docker-registry, amazon-ecr

Here's a beautiful related Q - "[How do I deploy updated Docker images to Amazon ECS tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34840137/how-do-i-deploy-updated-docker-images-to-amazon-ecs-tasks)"

But my concern is how to integrate this with CI/CD pipeline when using Jenkins for CI.

1. Using Jenkins or any Jenkin's plugin is it possible to push the recently build docker image to ECR.
2. Using Jenkins or any Jenkin's plugin is it possible to update the ECS container/**task** with the recently built or published (to ECR) image.

Answer (score 2):

you can using aws ecs cli comand to update your services

Comment: seems that could work.. +1. Will jenkins need a plugin for that - ECS

Comment: yes, you can do it, I using python code with command for execute my services

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the solution? What exactly should be done after pushing the new image? Is there a way just to restart the service?