# AWS ECS: How to force deploy service using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I want to force deploy an aws ECS service using aws cli.

What I want is shown below, but using aws cli. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48572274/1722326

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With AWS CLI you can do the following:

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster <value> --service <value> --force-new-deployment
```

[AWS CLI doc](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/update-service.html)