# AWS load balancer not running the latest image

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-ecr

I've setup an application load balancer with a simple "Hello World" greeting that was built on a Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./src .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

My buildspec.yaml to push this image to AWS ECR repo is below

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 18
    commands:
      - apt-get update
      - apt-get install -y nginx
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws --version
  build:
    commands:
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS 
      -- password-stdin 1234567.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
      - docker image build -t 1234567.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/demo-ecs-poc-ui .
      - docker push 1234567.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/demo-ecs-poc-ui
```

My app.js file in /src folder is:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.send('Hello World!');
});
app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

This works fine when I visit the load balancer DNS.

Now I changed this and added few react components and my Dockerfile looks like this now.

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
# Copy public directory to /app
COPY public/ /app/public
# Copy src directory to /app
COPY src/ /app/src
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
RUN npm i react-scripts
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

There is no change to the buildspec.yaml and I am using the same image.

When I used this Dockerfile, the new image(with react stuff) is pushed successfully to ECR, but when I visit the ALB DNS, it still uses the old image and prints that "Hello World!" instead of the react stuff I put in.

Is there any change I need to make to make my ALB point to the latest image in the ECR repo?
I thought it will always pick up the latest image from the ECR and serve that, probably I am wrong.

I am using 2 different pipeline stacks (one for creating aws resources and the other one for application where the Docker stuff comes into play).

Sorry not a Docker expert, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Load Balancers don't "run" docker images. An AWS Load Balancer just sends traffic to a target server. You would run a docker container from that image in either the ECS, EKS, or EC2 service, and configure the load balancer to send traffic to that running container. From your previous questions it looks like you are using ECS. Just pushing an updated image to ECR does not deploy a new docker container with that image. You need to update your ECS task definition to reference the new image, and then trigger an ECS service deployment with the new task definitin.

Comment: I agree. But what do I update in my ECS Task definition resource? It is pointing to Image: !Ref Image and the Image in my dev.json file is always "Image": "1234567.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/demo-ecs-poc-ui:latest". May be should I update ECS task definition manually from aws console? or re-create the entire stack?Even then I am not sure what to update....Sorry bit unclear here.

Comment: Using `latest` is a bad idea, specifically because of this sort of thing. If you were using unique tags per image, then you could obviously update the image reference to the new tag, and be sure that the new image was deployed after. You could force a new ECS deployment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34840137/how-do-i-deploy-updated-docker-images-to-amazon-ecs-tasks but if the service is running on ECS via EC2 deployments, the EC2 host may cache the `latest` image and not pull the new one, resulting in inconsistent deployments.

Comment: Thanks Mark, Using unique tags worked for me. I had to first push the image with a tag "docker push 1234567.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/demo-ecs-poc-ui:$MY_DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION" and then in the container definition I used "Image: !Join [":", [!Ref Image, !Ref DockerImageVersion]]"

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.