# ECS tasks takes lot of time to deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

This is the follow-up question to
[AWS load balancer not running the latest image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77531432/aws-load-balancer-not-running-the-latest-image/77531598?noredirect=1#comment136686503_77531598)

I am now tagging my Docker image every time I make change to my app. The tag goes like 1.0.0,1.0.1 etc so that ECS Service will pull the latest image when it runs the service.

When I tried with a new tag, my ECS service is deploying forever and it says "UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS"

During this process, when I checked the ECS console, I see 2 tasks, one running and one in "Stopped" status.
When I checked the stopped task, it says "Task failed ELB health checks" in my Target group.

So just wondering if I have to remove the previously running task before I can run a task with the latest image?

My second question is what should I do to fix the "Unknown" health status that's displayed next to the task?

I had no problem in deployment when I first deployed the service with a docker image. The problem started to happen only when I changed the tag number when building my docker image.

Any help much appreciated.